# What game is this knight-like character from?

Tags: game-identification

I found this picture/screenshot. What game is this? I've been looking for ages, but found nothing.

Can someone tell me what game is this?

[image: Knight in full armour]

Comment: Right click image, click "Search Google for this Image"

Comment: @Dom Honestly, that's surprisingly ineffective in this case. I did manage to get a couple of good hits on local game shops, but given how localized they were, I'm not sure everybody would get that helpful results. Otherwise, it's a bunch of random sites using (usualy a modified version) of the same image. In fact, Google's 'best guess' regaring the image is something called "chevalier d émeraude".

Answer (score 64):

The character is from the box art (and other promotional material, such as wallpapers) of [Heroes of Might and Magic V](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heroes_of_Might_and_Magic_V), altough the picture has been heavily photoshopped.
[image]